# Numpy, avoid loop in 3d array difference nested summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a simple problem for Numpy: I have 3d coordinates and I want to compute the overlap between two distinct configurations with the following function

```
def Overlap(rt, r0,a):
    s=0
    for i in range(len(rt)):
        s+=(( pl.norm(r0[i]-rt ,axis=1) <=a).astype('int')).sum()
    return s`
```

Where `rt` and `r0` represent two `m by 3` tables, the configurations.
Practically, it computes the distance between a vector in the first configuration and  any other vector in the second, checks for a threshold value `a`, and returns the total sum after a loop over all the positions. Is there a smart way to avoid the explicit for loop? I have the feeling that the complexity cannot really be changed, but there is maybe a way to avoid the slowness of the native for construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np
overlap = np.sum(cdist(rt, r0) <= a)
```

When `m` is 1000 on my machine, this is about 9x faster. It's much faster for small arrays

Comment: It is already quite a nice improvement! Thank you, I had forgotten to have a look at scipy...